# objective-c gettimeofday must be imported?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to use gettimeofday in Objective-C. However, i get these two issues:

1. "Implicit declaration of function 'gettimeofday' is invalid in C99"
2. "Declaration of 'gettimeofday' must be imported from module 'Darwin.POSIX.sys.time' before it is required"

I have performed these imports:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <time.h>
```

But the issue still persists?

Thanks in advance.
/JBJ

Answer (score 14, accepted):

import `<sys/time.h>` instead of `#include <time.h>`

in `C` `time.h` declares functions like time(), clock() etc; and In `POSIX` (OS specification) it has all `C` structure and macro and it is extended with time interval functions in `sys/time.h` .

Comment: @KDeogharkar, solved my problem as well. How would you explain the reason for this though?